# echo php variabel in HTML(wordpress)

Tags: php, if-statement, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a custom wordpress post type everything works but my client asked me to insert a function that doenst show the button if the link field is empty that is also working but when I want to display the tekst or link the part where the php is inserted just doesnt shows up what am I doing wrong

I am able to get the data on other parts of this php file but not in this part of the page

```
<?php 
   $linktitle = $day_aray=get_field("under_shoe_button_title");
   $linkexist = get_field("under_shoe_button_link");    
   echo($linktitle);
   if (empty($linkexist)) {    
       echo '<html> <p></p></html>' ;           
   }    
   else {       
       echo '<html>
       <a href="google.nl"  class="button primary is-bevel box-shadow-3 box-shadow-4-hover expand" style="border-radius:5px;" 
       </html> <?php echo($linktitle); ?> <html><span></span>
       <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
       </html>';    
   }
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple `<html>` tags? There should only be one for every document.

Comment: Suggest you go learn some HTML basics, before you start playing with server-side scripting ... that outputting multiple `html` elements inside one document makes no sense whatsoever should be clear to you upfront.

Comment: Instead of being rude like above... You don't need to wrap html in an html tag.  You only need one html tag at the start of the page and one at the end.  These are already included in wordpress's header.php and footer.php.  When echoing html with php, just echo the html you want to show, and don't wrap it in a now redundant `<html>` tag.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia I think you mistook Jerodev and CBroe's tone, I don't believe they were being rude at all.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton the elitist tone that coding noobs receive on this website irks me.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia Maybe you shouldn't assume the tone behind peoples typed words in a Q&A site? Their comments were perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton perhaps you're mistaking mine too :)

Comment: @JacobRaccuia you're the one accusing people of being rude :)

Comment: no problem at all I got it to work thx for the support guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would look carefully, you would notice, that you are echoing a string where, inside the string, you are trying to `echo` again. Even with little programming knowledge, you should understand, that it is not logical to do that.

The same goes for php opening `<?php` tag. You opened the tag at start of the page and later on, inside a string, you are trying to open it again. This does not work.

Instead, close the string (or escape it) and then add the `echo` option.

```
   echo '<html>
   <a href="google.nl"  class="button primary is-bevel box-shadow-3 box-shadow-4-hover expand" style="border-radius:5px;" 
   </html>';
   echo($linktitle);
   echo '<html><span></span>
   <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
   </html>';
```

And please, read the comments to you question and learn basic HTML

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong in your code

Firstly you are using `echo` inside `echo` you should use concatenation instead.

so you want to echo it like this

```
echo '<your html code>'.$linktitle.'<your other html code>';
```

Also your html code is wrong coz u are using many `html` tags.

Comment: that the way did the coding for the templaye so I just contineud